# What's the name of this kind of installer system for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I'm building a piece of software and looking around for an installer system in order to deliver it to the final client.

So far I have found many such as **Inno Setup, InstallShield**, and then **Nullsoft's NSIS**.

But during my research it came to my mind that Visual Studio has a very fancy one and very pleasant to the eyes. I'll attach an image in the post.

Do you know what system they use?

Thanks.

[image: Installer]

Image Credit: http://www.lahey.com/docs/lgf13help/LFGSInstallingVS.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found one, a system called Advanced Installer, they provide a rich installer with a lot of customizations, the visual studio installer uses the Surface UI theme.

Link: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/gallery.html